# Autonomous Database (Shared) OCPU and storage limits?

Tags: storage, cpu, oracle-autonomous-db

The user interface for Autonomous Database (Shared) seems to have an OCPU and storage limitation of 128 OCPUs and 128 TB. Is there a way to provision a database with more OCPU or TB than this?

Answer (score 1):

Autonomous Database on Shared Infrastructure has a 128 OCPU and 128 TB storage limit on the user interface. However, you may provision larger databases by contacting Oracle via a [service request](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Support%20Tools/1321379_1.html) or via your sales representative.

For more than 128 OCPUs, you may also enable auto-scaling to get immediate access to upto 3 x 128 OCPUs as your workload requires it.

Ref - I am a product manager on the Oracle Autonomous Database.